# Open App on Car Dock?

Tags: android

Is it possibe to have your app start automatically when the device is placed in the car doc? Like Google Maps, I know it utilizes the magnet in the dock. Where do I look in the API to accomplish this?

Thanks

Patrick

Answer (score 5):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Look for `CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK`

Comment: So all I have to do is add this Category to the activity in the manfest file?

Comment: You need an entry something like this:

<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: So I added <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" /> & left the original <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Tested on a MOTO Droid. it would not start the app. Is there more to this?