# Creating an application that shows up when an Android phone is docked

Tags: android, dock

What category or action would I use to make my application show up when the phone gets placed in a dock?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the phone gets doced?" Do you mean when the phone is placed in a car dock or desk dock?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yes I do mean car dock and desk dock. I tried to put <category android:name="android.category.CAR_DOCK AND DESK_DOCK" but it didn't really do anything but bring up the stock docking station on both. shouldn't ask if it wants to use the stock or my application upon dock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will launch the app automatically when docked

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.CAR_DOCK" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

Comment: Nice. Also works with DESK_DOCK which is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are looking to listen for an intent when the phone is put in a car dock such as is the case w/ the droid?  I would take a look at this post.

[Open App on Car Dock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267958/open-app-on-car-dock)